# Saving prediction images in python loop gets slower each iteration

Tags: python, loops, time

I am looping over prediction images from a cnn generated by the predict_generator() function in keras, and saving them using matplotlib> plt.savefig in a loop. For some reason every iteration of this loop is getting slower; after 2000 iterations the time to complete the loop has gone from <1s/it to ~56s/it. What might be causing the slowdown and and what can be done to resolve it?

The loop is structured as follows:

```
results = model.predict_generator(test_img_gen,len(os.listdir(child)),verbose=1)

for i,img in tqdm(enumerate(results)):
        plt.imshow(np.reshape(img,(512,512)), interpolation='nearest')
        resultDir = '{}_{}_{}.png'.format(resdir,filenames[i],str(i))
        plt.savefig(resultDir)
```

Comment: I suggest you to add `plt.figure()` just before `plt.imshow()` and also add `plt.close()` just after `plt.savefig()` inside your `for` loop.

Comment: Ravi's comment fixed the issue. Thanks. If you add it as an answer I will accept it :)